# Dúvidas - page rank do google

Tags: google, seo

Estou fazendo um site de trailer e novidades de filmes, está quase no fim o php.

Fiz um sistema pratico, ao adicionar na DB os dados do filme, ele mesmo organiza conforme a categoria mostrando 12 resultados por pagina.

Ao clicar na capa do filme por um exemplo "**Uma Noite No Museu 2**" vai estar com link `filmes.php?id=1`, e o registro `id 1` no DB vai estar todo conteúdo que defini do filme.

Porém a pagina "**filme.php**" ela é tipo um "*camaleão*" dependendo do `id` que tiver na url ela vai puxar o conteúdo diferente, em outras palavras não vou ter uma pagina no servidor pra cada filme e nem um link de diretorio, será que vou ter problemas com o google rankear minhas paginas na pesquisa pelo fato de não existirem ?

Estava pensando em modificar o link de cada filme no formato `filme?nome=uma-noite-no-museu-2` pra ficar mais visível o conforme estive lendo seria melhor oque acham?

Comment: Não é a URL que define ao google, apesar de "muitos repudiarem", você pode sim usar uma url não descritiva, desde que o conteúdo apresentado pela página seja "bem organizado". Mas se quiser usar uma url descritiva, eu pessoalmente não recomendo "querystrings", pois são difíceis do usuário "lembrar", prefira [urls amigaveis](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/url-amigável). Esse negocio de url não afeta o "rankeamento", não foque nisto, foque em apresentar um conteúdo organizado e de "qualidade" ao usuário final.

Comment: Obrigado Guilherme!

Comment: Assim que possível se eu tiver tempo formulo uma resposta, com exemplo de url amigavel.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento A URL faz sim MUITA diferença. Já trabalho com web há alguns anos e o que tenho visto é que, em nível de importância, o google costuma priorizar o seguinte: 1) Título da página 2) Palavras na URL da página; 3) Títulos / palavras chave em `h1`, `h2` e `h3`. Claro que isso não é uma receita de bolo e existem diversas outras variáveis, mas uma otimização básica focada nestes pontos te ajuda a rankear seu site bem mais rápido.

Comment: @AndréRibeiro Em "Rankeamento" acho que não, o que eu quero dizer, não adianta url amigável, sem um conteúdo relevante. Podemos dizer que ajuda, mas não é de "alto impacto".

Answer (score -3):

URL amigável é um dos fatores de rankeamento, assim sendo voce poderá estar melhor posicionado na SERP com uma URL amigável do que com outra sem, Sem a URL amigável dará mais trabalho ao google para decifrá-la e encaixá-la no resultado certo. Embora o algoritmo do google seja bem inteligente e pode rankear a sua página pelo conteúdo interno mas não custa dar uma ajudinha ao mesmo. De certeza ele olha também o que está escrito na URL para melhor rankear.